# How to count value from JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following data in my DB.

```
id     title               genre_id
1      Khiladi               ["5"]
2      Sanam              ["2","5","20"]
3      Raaz                 ["10"]
```

now i want to count the match genre_id like 5 = 2, 10=1
i get the result normal values not JSON.

suppose `$genre_id =5;` then by following I get 1 but desire result is 2

```
$this->db->where('genre_id' , $genre_id);
```

Comment: Please, do not store arrays in columns like `["2","5","20"]`. Use multiple records instead.

Comment: one single column must only have one atomic value we called it 1NF. Also please explore your question a bit more. So we can help you.

Comment: which 5 you are talking about? @nady gold

Comment: @NomanJaved if $genre_id = 5 then I want to count it and desire result is 2, but now it shows 1

Comment: @nadygold your question is still not clear.! please explore it in proper way so everyone get what you want. As you are saving array and willing to fetch result as an id..! I don't think so it will work in what way you are trying.!

Comment: see in where condition i want to check genre_id = "5" 
after check the condition i want to get count values like 5=2

Comment: you cant (without a load of extra cost) get what you want - unless you change your db design following the first 2 comments.

Comment: First you need to save data in proper format then you can perform actions...!
`id     title               genre_id`
`1      khiladi              5`
`2      sanam               2`
`3      sanam               5`
`4      sanam               20`
`5      raaz                 10`

Comment: @NomanJaved better would be an extra table for that n2n connection; your suggestion would also violate 1NF (double entries)

Answer (score 0):

Inseted of using this format of saving records in database.

```
id     title               genre_id
1      Khiladi               ["5"]
2      Sanam              ["2","5","20"]
3      Raaz                 ["10"]
```

You can use the single atomic value in one column that is Normalization form of data. Like this way, this is pretty simple way. You can also use `multiple tables` with many to many relation if you want.

```
id     title               genre_id
1      khiladi              5
2      sanam                2
3      sanam                5
4      sanam                20
5      raaz                 10
```

Then you can query like you desire. Like you want to `count 5` from column `genre_id`. Now you can use this query you will get your desired result.

```
$this->db->where('genre_id', $genre_id);
$this->db->from("table_name");
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Hope this solution will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is what is called a "many-to-many" relationship. You have a list of titles and a list of genres and you need to know how they relate to each other. Although your design is very fast for answering the question "what genres apply to the title 'Sanam'?" it is very difficult for it to answer the other question: What titles are in genre 5? As you have already discovered.

Generally in a relational database like MySQL many-to-many relationships are represented using three tables. I will give you a very brief introduction here, but if you search for "MySQL many-to-many" you will find a host of information, some written for beginners.

Your tables might look something like:

```
#Table Titles
id  |  title
--------------
1   | Khiladi
2   | Sanam
3   | Raaz
```

There might be other information about the title (description, maybe) but not information that might apply to other title (like genre or director).

You would have a similar table for the genres:

```
#Table Genres
id  |  title
--------------
1   | Action
2   | Comedy
3   | Romance
```

So how do you know which genres go with which titles? You create a third table that as a row for each RELATIONSHIP.

```
#Table Title_has_Genre
title_id  | genre_id
----------------------
1         | 5
2         | 2
2         | 5
2         | 10
```

and so forth.

Now you can get the ids of all the titles that are in genre 5 easily, and you can also get the ids of all the genres associated with a title.

Generally you will use `JOIN` syntax in your queries so you get the name of the title, or the description of the genre, or whatever else you need.